# Receber dados de JSON externo por PHP

Tags: php, json

Estou tentando receber um arquivo externo JSON via PHP. Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
<?php

$json_file = file_get_contents(
     "http://www.moonwalk.com.br/api/VitrineDeProdutos/58e903df295cbc5c4639434d4c35090d");

$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);

$itens = $json_str->nodes;

foreach ( $itens as $e ) 
    { echo "$e->title<br>"; } 
?>
```

Mas não estou conseguindo nenhum resultado.

<strike>O arquivos JSON externo está [neste endereço](http://www.moonwalk.com.br/api/VitrineDeProdutos/58e903df295cbc5c4639434d4c35090d).</strike>

Estou fazendo algo errado?

Comment: Eu não posso responder, mais essa é uma boa formas, veja uma api de cotação como exemplo: <?php 
$json_str = file_get_contents("https://economia.awesomeapi.com.br/json/all/USD-BRL,EUR-BRL");   
$jsonObj = json_decode($json_str);
$usd = $jsonObj->USD;
$eur = $jsonObj->EUR;
 ?>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O segundo parâmetro do **[json_decode](https://www.php.net/json_decode)()** é para forçar o resultado do decode à estrutura de um array associativo.

O seu código está correcto se não tiver `true` no **json_decode**.

Se tiver `true` então deve esperar uma array associativa, e nesse caso pode usar:

```
$json_file = file_get_contents("http://www.moonwalk.com.br/api/VitrineDeProdutos/58e903df295cbc5c4639434d4c35090d");   
$json_str = json_decode($json_file, true);
$itens = $json_str['nodes'];

foreach ( $itens as $e ) 
    { echo $e['title']."<br>"; }
```

### [Exemplo](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/spu-y7q)

Answer (score 6):

Consgue obter o resultado, removendo o `true` do `json_decode()`.

```
json_decode($json_file);
```

> json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] ) php.net

O segundo parâmetro força o retorno de [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) a ser  um array associativo, enquanto nas linhas abaixo vc estava tentando acessar um objeto.

```
$itens = $json_str->nodes;
```

Caso tenha algum erro na conversão use as funções [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) (desde o php5.3) e [json_last_error_msg()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) (desde php5.5) para detectar a causa.

Comment: Li a documentação e deu certo assim : json_decode($arquivo); e depois json_decode($arquivo, true);

Answer (score 0):

Você quer receber um objeto json tipo esse?

```
{
    "nome" : "ra"
}
```

Exemplo e envio (POST)

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('http://localhost:8080/usuariosapi.php');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_POST);

$request->setQueryData(array(
  'acao' => 'consultarpornome'
));

$request->setHeaders(array(
  'postman-token' => 'd26d9873-4dda-705f-55a3-512f4acd3e18',
  'cache-control' => 'no-cache'
));

$request->setBody('{
    "nome" : "ra"
}');

try {
  $response = $request->send();

  echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
  echo $ex;
}
```

No arquivo PHP de destino você utilizar esse comando para recuperar o objeto JSON

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');  

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

Espero que lhe ajude

Comment: Esse `new HttpRequest();` é de qual biblioteca?

Comment: Dessa http://php.net/manual/it/class.httprequest.php, mas foi apenas um exemplo poderia ser um envio via ajax também.