# Atribuir valores de JSON a variáveis simples

Tags: php, json, array

Estou tendo problemas na leitura de um JSON que recebo:

```json
{"data":{"charges":{"data":{"charges":[{"code":10006756,"dueDate":"13/09/2014","link":"https://www.teste.com.br"}]},"success":true}
```

Preciso atribuir esses valores a minhas variáveis, esse array sempre terá 1 registro, é regra.

Como pegar todas variáveis dele (`code`, `dueData`, `link` e `success`) e atribuir esse valores a variáveis simples? Ou seja em meu código vou ter:

```php
$code  = valordoJSON;
$dueData    = valordoJSON;
$link  = valordoJSON;
$sucesso    = valordoJSON;
```

Comment: [relacionado](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4410/91)

Answer (score 6):

Você pode usar a função [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php). Essa função recebe uma `String` no formato JSON e te retorna um [objeto](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.object.php) ou [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php) com as propriedades do JSON.

Segue um exemplo bem simples:

```
$json = '{"nome": "Bruno", "sobrenome": "da Silva", "idade": "37"}';

//transforma o JSON em um objeto
$objeto = json_decode($json);

echo 'Nome: ' . $objeto->nome;
echo 'Sobrenome: ' . $objeto->sobrenome;
echo 'Idade: ' . $objeto->idade;
```

Caso você não queira um objeto, pode transformar o JSON em um `array`, passando `true` como segundo parâmetro da função:

```
$json = '{"nome": "Bruno", "sobrenome": "da Silva", "idade": "37"}';

//transforma o JSON em um array
$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo 'Nome: ' . $array['nome'];
echo 'Sobrenome: ' . $array['sobrenome'];
echo 'Idade: ' . $array['idade'];
```

Answer (score 0):

parece que a parte {"data":{"charges":{"data":{"charges" esta duplicada fora isso:

```
<?php
$obj = json_decode('{"data":{"charges":[{"code":10006756,"dueDate":"13/09/2014","link":"https://www.teste.com.br"}]},"success":true}');

$code  = $obj->data->charges[0]->code;
$dueData = $obj->data->charges[0]->dueDate;
$link = $obj->data->charges[0]->link;
$sucess = $obj->success;

echo $code;
echo $dueData;
echo $link;
echo $sucess;
?>
```

Comment: Um array multidimensional pode repetir as chaves, veja: `{"id":[{"id":2, "a":"1", "b":"2"}]}`, o resultado é: `array(id=>array(0=>array(id=>2,a=>1,b=>2)))`

Comment: sim, mas no exemplo dele parece estar repetido, pois os dois primeiro `{"data":{"charges":` não são fechados

Comment: Eu sei, mas o exemplo que você usou, passa a impressão de que  haveria colisão em caso de chaves com mesmo nome - **fiz apenas uma observação** pois alterou o array. O json da questão esta errado mesmo, parece ter sido escrito manualmente.