# Tratar JSON de consulta API Facebook

Tags: php, api, facebook

Estou fazendo requisições das postagens de um usuário para a **API do Facebook** como no código abaixo.

```
//faz requisição
$postagens = file("https://graph.facebook.com/".$url."/posts?access_token=".$token);
//imprime as postagens
echo $postagens[0];
```

e estou tendo um retorno no formato JSON, preciso separar as postagens para agrupar da forma desejada, estou tentando usar a função explode(), mas não estou tendo sucesso. alguma conselho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a função `json_decode($var)`.

Ao receber os dados basta fazer um `foreach` para imprimi-los.

Veja uma pergunta relacionada com a sua e a quarta resposta do Sérgio.

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4413/23919