# Como decodificar o JSON a seguir? PHP

Tags: php, api, facebook

```
{
   "data": {
      "app_id": "0000000",
      "scopes": [
         "public_profile"
      ],
      "user_id": "00000000"
   }
}
```

Eu quero pegar o USER ID com o json_decode.

Como pego?

Comment: Duplicada? [Receber dados de JSON externo por PHP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4410/91)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$json = '{
   "data": {
      "app_id": "0000000",
      "scopes": [
         "public_profile"
      ],
      "user_id": "00000000"
   }
}';

//json_decode retornando um objeto
$object = json_decode($json);
$user_id = $object->{data}->{user_id};

//json_decode retornando um array associativo
$array_associativo = json_decode($json,true);
$user_id = $array_associativo['data']['user_id'];
```

Referência: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

basta usar a varíavel que contém o JSON e utilizar o índice:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input',true)); // <---- Usei esse exemplo, mas você pode usar qualquer "raw JSON"

// $json no momento contém o objeto total

$data = $json->{'data'};
$user_id = $data->{'user_id'};
```