# como fazer parser de um retorno json com objeto complexo

Tags: php, json, parser

Como faço um parser de um retorno **json** onde tenho campos opcionais, como telefone, o usuário pode ter mais de um como residencial, celular e telefone para recado, neste caso se o usuário informou o telefone ele lista caso não tenho informado ele não lista nenhum ou apenas um ou dois, segue o exemplo de um retorno abaixo.

```
{
     "transacao":{
        "codigo":1,
        "nome":"bruno",
        "sobrenome":"richart",
        "idade":28,
        "endereco":{
           "rua":"Avenidas das Americas",
           "numero":12300,
           "bairro":"Barra da Tijuca",
           "cidade":"Andradina",
           "uf":"rj"
        },
        "telefone":[
           {
              "tipo":"residencial",
              "ddd":18,
              "numero":37236207
           },
           {
              "tipo":"celular",
              "ddd":18,
              "numero":972770022
           }
        ],
        "compra":{
           "idproduto":23,
           "descricao":"Celular Iphone",
           "quantidade":1
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Quando não tem telefone ele nem aparece essa chave? é isso? você quer saber quando tem essa chave ou não?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Sim, no caso o telefone seria um array, poderia ter até 3 telefones, mas o sistema só iria fazer o parser se existir pelo menos um telefone.

Comment: Possível duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4410/receber-dados-de-json-externo-por-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para indentificar uma chave de telefone nesse [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php) seria:

```
//cria um array associativo quando segundo paramentro é true
$array = json_decode($json, true); 
//retorna true se a chave existir
array_key_exists('telefone', $array['transacao']);
```

o código:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
if (array_key_exists('telefone', $array['transacao']))
{
    foreach($arr['transacao']['telefone'] as $telefone)
    {
        echo $telefone['tipo'];
        echo $telefone['ddd'];
        echo $telefone['numero'];           
    }
}
```

***Referencias:***

- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php)
- [array](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array.php)
- [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php)

isso evita dar erros.

Answer (score 2):

É só usar `json_decode($json,true)` desta forma você irá criar um array associativo.

Exemplo:

```
<?php
        $json = '{
     "transacao":{
        "codigo":1,
        "nome":"bruno",
        "sobrenome":"richart",
        "idade":28,
        "endereco":{
           "rua":"Avenidas das Americas",
           "numero":12300,
           "bairro":"Barra da Tijuca",
           "cidade":"Andradina",
           "uf":"rj"
        },
        "telefone":[
           {
              "tipo":"residencial",
              "ddd":18,
              "numero":37236207
           },
           {
              "tipo":"celular",
              "ddd":18,
              "numero":972770022
           }
        ],
        "compra":{
           "idproduto":23,
           "descricao":"Celular Iphone",
           "quantidade":1
        }
     }
  }';


$arr = json_decode($json,true);

foreach($arr['transacao']['telefone'] as $telefone){
    print_r($telefone);
}
```

Veja funcionando em : [PHPSandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c53ea59fab1f4962ad7bf4bee2820b48debc4a2e)

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente muito obrigado, só fiquei em duvida caso não tenha nenhum telefone, existe alguma função que verifique e trate o erro?

Comment: @BrunoRichart se não tiver nenhum telefone dentro do objeto `['telefone']` não vai entrar no Loop, você só tem que ter certeza que esse objeto vai vir (mesmo que vazio), caso não consiga garantir isto, cheque antes com `isset($arr['transacao']['telefone'])` se existir vai retornar true