# pegando os valores recebido do json_decode

Tags: php, json

Então eu tenho esse código

```
$result = json_decode($output, true);

var_dump($result);
```

ele esta gerando o seguinte.

```
    array(3){
  [
    "status"
  ]=>string(9)"completed"[
    "flights"
  ]=>array(2){
    [
      "outbound"
    ]=>array(9){
      [
        "E_0830_1140_2176"
      ]=>array(6){
        [
          "Flight"
        ]=>array(14){
          [
            "class"
          ]=>string(1)"E"[
            "airline"
          ]=>string(2)"G3"[
            "number"
          ]=>string(4)"2176"[
            ---------------------->**"from"**
          ]=>string(3)"GIG"[
            "to"
          ]=>string(3)"FOR"[
            "departure"
          ]=>int(1523532600)[
            "departure_date"
          ]=>string(10)"2018-04-12"[
            "departure_time"
          ]=>string(5)"08:30"[
            "arrival"
          ]=>int(1523544000)[
            "arrival_date"
          ]=>string(10)"2018-04-12"[
            "arrival_time"
          ]=>string(5)"11:40"[
            "flight_time"
          ]=>int(11400)[
            "str_flight_time"
          ]=>string(5)"3h10m"[
            "national"
          ]=>bool(true)
        }
```

gostaria de pegar o resultado do "from" por EX e joga-lo no "echo" e trazer ele separadamente para poder estilizar o mesmo.

Comment: você acessa o json por php mesmo?

Comment: sim, faço a chamada do json pelo PHP, depois uso o decode para me retornar os valores buscados em php, $result = json_decode($output, true);

Comment: pego o resultado e ele gera um url, dai pego os resultados dessa url e jogo em minha pagina...

codigo que uso para pegar a url e joga ro resulto na mesma.

 $curl = curl_init();
    $url = $cap_url;
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $cap_url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

Comment: Aqui está a solução => https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4410/receber-dados-de-json-externo-por-php

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Receber dados de JSON externo por PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4410/receber-dados-de-json-externo-por-php)

Comment: então no caso ficaria 

$itens = $result['from'];
  
  foreach ( $itens as $e ) 
  { echo $e['in-pra']."<br>"; }

Comment: deu erro de  Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo do array original?
Posso te ajudar se tiver um exemplo do json original.